# Looking for a young adult, scifi, romance, simulation I read in the late nineties or early 00s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Futuristic society where partnering and breeding were led by the government. Love and emotion were suppressed.

A group of young people begin almost experimenting with emotion and find themselves in trouble. They are sent into some sort of simulation where they experience a life of pain, ending in what I believe is a scene where they are burned alive in a building surrounded by the people they have come to love. I think it might have even been holocaust adjacent.

Eventually they are released from the situation, having "learned their lesson."